# Was the cloud of the dog related to Sirius Black in any way?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the film version of *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, during the Quidditch match, we see a cloud formation which looks a great deal like The Grim or Sirius Black's animagus.  **Was that cloud formation of a dog related to Sirius Black in any way?** i.e. did Black conjure it up as a sign to Harry, or was it just mere luck?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have a different take on the answer, although it mixes canon, reference books, and movie canon. In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, the novel, Professor Trelawney specifically says that the Grim haunts churchyards:

> ‘The Grim, my dear, the Grim!’ cried Professor Trelawney, who looked shocked that Harry hadn’t understood. ‘The giant, spectral dog **that haunts churchyards**! My dear boy, it is an omen – the worst omen – of *death*!’
>   <sub>*Prisoner of Azkaban* - page 83 - Chapter 6, *Talons and Tealeaves* - Bloomsbury</sub>

Now, we all know Professor Trelawney is a bit of a windbag. The movie and book show us that representations of the Grim can be demonstrated outside of a churchyard, first in Harry's tea leaves in both the book and movie versions of *Prisoner of Azkaban*. However, the movie scene with the dog-like figure in the clouds in *Prisoner of Azkaban*, the movie* is not the Grim:

> In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* [the movie], Padfoot, **who is mistaken for the Grim**. was a computer-generated Animagus.
>   <sub>[***Harry Potter: The Creature Vault***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062374230) by Jody Revenson - page 104 - Chapter Five, *Shape Shifters* - Harper Collins</sub>

Let's put book canon aside. I'd suggest that, in the movie, Harry's paranoia of dying was so heightened that he mistakenly imagined a group of clouds as the image of the Grim. The quote from *Harry Potter: The Creature Vault* confirms that Sirius's Animagus form is mistaken for the Grim.

So, was the cloud formation in *Prisoner of Azkaban* related to Sirius Black?

**No, it was not, because *Harry Potter: The Creature Vault* verifies that Sirius's Animagus form was not related to the Grim. Also, at the time that Harry supposedly saw "the Grim" in the movie *Prisoner of Azkaban*, Harry was completely unaware that Sirius is an Animagus**

[image: Teacup Grim]

Representation of the Grim in one of Trelawney's teacups, in the movie *Prisoner of Azkaban*.

[image: Cloud Grim]

Representation of the Grim, as Harry sees it, in the movie *Prisoner of Azkaban*.

[image: Sirius Black in his Animagus form]

Sirius Black in his Animagus form -- originally mistaken for the Grim -- dragging Ron toward the Whomping Willow in the movie *Prisoner of Azkaban*.

Comment: @N_Soong -- Haha, yes, well, she *is* a bit of one :)) JKR describes Trelawney as somewhat of a charlatan, manipulative, and grandiose. Charlatan, I can believe! (Well the others, too, not to mention Trelawney's a drunk to boot!).

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is the scene you are referring to:

[image: A dog shaped cloud from a scene in Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkaban.]

this scene was only added in the movie, probably for dramatic effect.
In the book what actually happens is that Harry sees a silhouette of Sirius (as a dog) at the top of the stands but he vanishes in the blink of an eye.

http://www.bustle.com/articles/31259-harry-potter-the-prisoner-of-azkaban-book-to-movie-differences-are-huge-its-time-we-admit

> Instead of seeing Sirius in his Animagus form of the big, black dog
>   sitting by the stands during his quidditch match like Harry does in
>   the book, the film has Harry see a cloud in the shape of the Grim as
>   he flies towards the snitch.

So this dog in the cloud can be said to be related to Sirius or not, based on how much you consider the movie a canon source

Comment: That's exactly the scene I am referring to.  +1